# GeoServer: Creating a datastore with spaces in the path

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, data-source

I am using the GeoServer REST API to create a datastore. The path that I am using has a space in it. This does not seem to work well in GeoServer 2.11.2 since it generates an "Input type is not supported" error.

When I go in GeoServer and I use the datastore page directly this does not seem to work unless you replace the spaces with %20 and the file: to file://.

So it works if the url field looks like this: file://C:source/example%20source/example.ecw

I can not get it to work with these paths in the REST call:

- C:/sources/example source/example.ecw (throws org.geoserver.rest.RestletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported input type)
- C:/sources/example%20source/example.ecw (throws file not found)
- <strike>file://C:/sources/example%20source/example.ecw (this converts in geoserver to file://file:) (throws file not found)</strike>

Is there a way I can make this work with the REST API?
Maybe GeoServer should support spaces natively?

---

the last option works but there was something in my code already adding the "file:" part so it added it double

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not so much the space as that you are not using a proper URL.

A url must start with `http://`,`https://` or `file://` and it must have special characters encoded (so convert spaces to %20 etc).

You don't say which language you are using to create your rest request but most languages have a method for converting a file to a URL and for encoding the URL if it contains special characters.